# Azure Devops REST API 203 returned

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-devops-extensions

When users signup for our application, we ask them to go through the oAuth process. We ask them for their organisation first, so we can use the access token we receive during oauth to make requests.

Here is a sample of the code we use to do that:

```
var client = new RestClient();
var createItemRequest = new RestRequest("https://app.vssps.visualstudio.com/oauth2/token", Method.POST);
string body = $"client_assertion_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:client-assertion-type:jwt-bearer&" +
              $"client_assertion={HttpUtility.UrlEncode(clientSecret)}&grant_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer" +
              $"&assertion={HttpUtility.UrlEncode(code)}&redirect_uri={redirectUrl}";

var formData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(body);
createItemRequest.AddParameter("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", formData, ParameterType.RequestBody);
var accessTokenResponse = client.Execute(createItemRequest).Content;
_logger.LogInformation($"accessToken response: {accessTokenResponse}");
var accessTokenObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AccessTokenResponse>(accessTokenResponse);

if (accessTokenObject != null
        && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(accessTokenObject.AccessToken)
        && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(accessTokenObject.RefreshToken))
{   
    _logger.LogInformation($"We have access token and refresh");
}
```

We always manage to get the refresh + access tokens for every user. Directly after this call we make a "get all projects call" to test the connection and tokens. For some users signing up when we make this call to check we can see them, some users receive a 203 response when we use the access token to make the first call (to get a list of projects). The request looks like:

[image]

The HTML returns:

[image: html response]

My question is, why do some users receive a 203 and some not? We have NO idea of what to tell the user when this happens - what do they check? Why does this happen? And how can they fix it?

Comment: "some users receive a 203 response when we use the access token to make the first call" that means the error 203 only occurred on the first time? or always? Have you check the the bearer format is correct in their scripts, like add colon `: ` before the bearer token. You could ask them to check it with postman and share the result.

Comment: Hi @Leo. No it's all our scripts. We take the access token and refresh after they accept on the scopes/permissions screen and store it and then make the projects API call. Most of time we get a response which is fine and get projects.... But I'd expect if the user did not have access to the Projects themselves they would get a Unauthorised not 203. Try it yourself by signing up for backrightup.com.

Comment: I'd check two things:

Is the error consistent for a user - i.e. can it succeed when retried after some time?

Is the error consistent across organisation - i.e. does it happen for all users in a given org? - this might indicate that it depends on org configuration.

Comment: Its likely an issue with the actual user's permissions. But we don't know for sure..

Comment: Its likely an issue with the actual user's permissions. But we don't know for sure..